# How can a request resolve to a different domain while keeping URI information?

Tags: nginx

I have 2 domains `domain.xyz` and `domainxyz.com`

I have the boilerplate for a dynamic routing service set up on `domain.xyz` which serves `domain.xyz/example-uri`.

I would like to make `domainxyz.com/example-uri` resolve to `domain.xyz/example-uri`

On the server I am using Nginx to direct requests on port 80 to the React app

Answer (score 0):

instead of using a dns redirect to resolve the .com to the .xyz (which is what I was initially doing), direct both domains to the nginx server. Then configure the nginx server like this:

source/explanation: https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.domainxyz.com domainxyz.com;

        location / {
            return 301 $scheme://domain.xyz$request_uri;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        }   
    }

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.domain.xyz domain.xyz;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        }   
    }
```